# How should I correct my link code so that it works on Github?

Tags: github, hyperlink

I am new to coding and I have been working on a webpage that I have put up on Github.
My Home/index page shows up fine.

Here is the link: https://mgettsdev.github.io/New-My-First-Website/

But when I click on the "`About Me`" or "`Contact`" in the Nav bar, I get the `404 no page found`.
The links all work on Replit, but I can't get them to work on Github at all.

Here is how I have written the code for the links:

```html
 <a href="/about.html">About Me</a> 
 <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
```

If anyone has any suggestions of how I could correct this so that the links will work it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The links work for me (Firefox).

Comment: I hope that is fake data. Putting your full name, date of birth and city could lead to ID theft.

Answer (score 0):

If you use relative instead of absolute URL path for your About link, that would work.

Meaning, in [github.com/MGettsDev/New-My-First-Website/index.html#L17](https://github.com/MGettsDev/New-My-First-Website/blob/ced9e4de20cc4104012e56803c8fd6adfdcae8be/index.html#L17)

```html
 <a href="about.html">About Me</a> <!-- About Me page link -->
 <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> <!-- Contact page link -->
```

(`"about.html"`, not `"/about.html"`)

An `/about.html` would ink to `https://mgettsdev.github.io/about.html`